# How to solve the Bash error "syntax error near unexpected token"?

Tags: linux, bash

I am receiving an error within CentOS saying

> 'line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `then' and 'syntax error: unexpected end of file'

The point of this code is to ask a user for a filename and then either copy move or delete the file based off what they pick.

```
echo "Please enter the file name you wish to alter: "
read filename

if [ -f $filename ]; then
echo "Please enter either C, M, or D to copy, move or delete the file: "
read op
        if [ "$op" = "C" ] || [ "$op" = "c" ]; then
echo "Please enter the destination directory in which you wish to copy to$
read dest
cp $filename $dest/$filename
echo "Complete"

elif [ "$op" = "M"] || [ "$op" = "m" ]; then
echo "Please enter the destination directory in which you wish to move to$
read dest
mv $filename $dest/$filename
echo "Complete"

elif [ "$op" = "D"] || [ "$op" = "d" ]; then
rm -i $filename
echo "Complete"

else "$filename does not exists try again."

fi
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I can see that echo at 6-10 are not properly handled. I think checking that will solve your issue.

Comment: consider cutting-n-pasting your code (along with appropriate shebang - `#!/bin/bah` ?) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/), make the recommended changes, and if you're still having problems then update the question with your latest code and a description of the new issue(s); at a minimum you have a) improperly terminated `echo` commands, b) improplery formatted tests and c) improperly terminated `if`

Comment: `to$`. Also, double quote all your variables.

Comment: There is certainly an issue at `elif [ "$op" = "M"] || [ "$op" = "m" ]; then` The command `[` expects its final argument to be `]`, but you have given it the argument `M]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third `echo` command has an unterminated string literal:

```
echo "Please enter the destination directory in which you wish to copy to$
```

Perhaps you wanted to write this instead:

```
echo "Please enter the destination directory in which you wish to copy to:"
```

The fifth `echo` command has the same problem.

Also, this statement is not valid:

```
else "$filename does not exists try again."
```

Perhaps you wanted to write this instead:

```
else
    echo "$filename does not exists try again."
```

Also, there is no `fi` corresponding to the first `if` statement.

Also, the syntax `[ "$op" = "M"]` is invalid. You must have a space before the `]` character, like this: `[ "$op" = "M" ]`.

You have the same problem again in `[ "$op" = "D"]`.

Comment: The " has been added to those sentences I am purely getting the unexpected end of file error.

Answer (score 0):

On line 7, you are closing your brackets too fast:
Instead of:

```
if [ "$op" = "C"]  ||  ["$op" = "c" ]; then
```

you should have:

```
if [ "$op" = "C"  ||  "$op" = "c" ]; then
```